# Is it more efficient to copy the data in a local worksheet or not?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro in an Excel file (let's call it AAA) that loops through the lines of one of the worksheets and looks-up additional data stored in a separate Excel file (let's call it BBB).
In order to look up the data, I need to filter, sort and search the data in BBB.
Everything works fine, my question is, will I gain anything in terms of computational time (i.e. speed) if instead of doing all the actions in BBB I first copy paste the values in an extra worksheet in AAA (and close BBB)?
Important to mention is that BBB only contains plain values, no formulas (so no risk of recalculating lots of data at each iteration).

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code.  If everything is working, you may want to post the code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. Note that the question guidelines there are different, so read through the [how to ask](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly; no, very little provided you declare a variable for BBB:

```
Dim wbBBB as workbook
Set wbBBB = etc etc
```

The compiler is using a pointer to BBB which costs next to nothing, so feel free to reference other workbooks without moving the data to the original workbook. Just be careful to avoid Select statements and the like, always reference the data directly, not from ActiveCell.

To expand upon your question; reading and writing from worksheets is very expensive, with a few exceptions. One exception is that storing the contents of a range into an array is very fast. So I'd suggest reading AAA into an array and BBB into an array. Assuming for example both sheets have data in Range A1 to D500:

```
Dim aaa() as Variant, bbb() as Variant

aaa = sheets("myAaaSheet1").Range("A1:D500").Value
bbb = sheets("myBbbSheet1").Range("A1:D500").Value
```

Then instead of working with the worksheets work with the arrays. There are many ways to work with arrays that are beyond the scope of this question but you can find lots of information online e.g. [cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)